# debugging jquery conflict

Tags: jquery, joomla

I have a site built on Joomla.  Joomla uses mootools, while most extensions use jquery. I have a template I use in Joomla that seems to have an issue with my registration page.  If I change my template everything works fine.

I believe it is a jquery conflict guessing from some searches on my yootheme template I use.  I'm getting nothing from the template creators.

Firebug doesn't show anything.  Any tips on how I can debug any issues here?

Comment: Can you give us more information?  What's the desired behavior and what is happening instead?

Comment: During registration no validation is taking place. For example, a visitor can enter without selecting the terms of service checkbox.  Correct behavior would be to disallow registration.  Or another example, a password mismatch, email mismatch, password strength etc.

Comment: sounds like it's time for a lot of console.log()s

Answer (score 1):

this is a namespacing issue. mootools and jquery (aside from the original `jQuery()`) uses the same `$()`-named function for it's selectors. using both on the same site, one will conflict the other. however, since mootools is native to Joomla and your jQuery is the "visitor" framework, you can change the namespace of jQuery using the [.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) function.

```
//future uses of jQuery will use "j" instead of "$"
//i think you can still use the original "jQuery()" also
var j = jQuery.noConflict();

//instead of:
$("selector");

//now you use:
j("selector");

//or
jQuery("selector");
```

declare `.noConflict()` just after you loaded your jQuery, but load both of these before Joomla's mootools script. also, whatever jQuery scripts that come in plugins, make sure to change their `$()` to the namespace you changed, or `jQuery()`

Comment: Thanks for the response.  In fact I do use this for all my custom code.  However in this case I'm stuck debugging the code from this template.  They do load a separate noconflict.js file but I can't be sure this covers it. So what I'm looking for is tips on how I can debug this further.

Comment: YooTheme build pretty solid templates. I'd be amazed if they built a template that failed in this way. More likely you have an add-on (probably module) installed that causes a conflict. Switching templates possibly resolves this by chance - for example the module with the clash might be published to a position not present in the alternate template thus module isn't output and can't clash.  A link would enable the quickest help.

Comment: that's why i stopped using Joomla. Creating a frankenstein website using a heavy CMS and strap-on features is quite a hassle to the user, and much more to the developer. Joomla shouldn't use a foreign framework if it were to cater extensibility, it should make it's own.

Comment: @DeanMarshall I'm also surprised that yootheme would have this issue, but switching templates does fix this issue. I wish I could provide a link but this is a development site.  I will try looking at modules but I feel I've taken pretty much everything down and only left the template up.

Comment: If it were a jQuery Mootools conflict I'd expect to see a javascript error of one sort or another in the javascript console - and in web dev toolbar's icons.  Try validating your html, I've seen badly broken html break javascript functionality without causing js errors.